# How to switch the page numbering from Roman to Arabic for a range of pages?

Tags: pdf, page-numbers

I have a PDF file (of a *scanned* ~857-page document) whose pages, when I view the file with Acrobat (or any other PDF viewer I've tried so far), are shown as being numbered with Roman numbers all the way through.  This does not agree with the page numbers shown by the scanned page images.

More specifically, when viewed with Acrobat (for example), from the third page to the last one, the page numbers shown in the toolbar range from v to dccclix.  For the first and second pages no numbers at all are shown.  This numbering matches the scanned images for the first 14 pages, but the same cannot be said for the remaining pages.  The numbering for the remaining pages should use Arabic numbers, starting at 1.

> How can I change the page numbering so that it corresponds to the numbering shown in the scanned page images?

Thanks!

---

PS: My first strategy for fixing this was to first convert the document to Word (expecting that changing page numbers would be easier to do in Word), but the conversion failed miserably.  (The problems with the converted document are too many to mention: equations garbled beyond recognition, figures gone, etc.; in retrospect, it is clear that the contents of this document pretty much rule out any solution that would require converting the file to any other format.)

PS2: FWIW, I don't know anything about how this file was generated, so there's no way for me to track the source of this problem.  Nor I have access to the original, so a re-scan is out of the question (even if I could bring myself to re-scan 857 pages!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the "Pages" icon (which is the top icon among those that are aligned vertically along the left edge of the page); this should reveal a panel along the left-hand side of the window, showing the icons for all the pages, aligned vertically.  Click on the label "Options" in the top section of this panel.  Choose Number Pages...  From this point on, the procedure is self-explanatory.

For a different explanation, see

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3993593#jive-correctAnswer-container-cc